# Vue + Vuetify Chrome visual glitches

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, vuetify.js

After a very recent Chrome update I've started seeing very weird visual glitches on Chrome on a Vue site that uses Vuetify. It's difficult to even describe the issue, but it looks something like this:

[image]

Semi-transparent (and sometimes opaque) blocks appear and disappear as different elements get focus and as you scroll. I get this in chrome in both Windows and Mac. Also in an updated Edge (which is chromium based) but not in Firefox or Safari.

Video: https://youtu.be/_zzYtrMovsE

That semi-transparent red block is my theme's primary colour. I've tried changing my theme colour to blue and this changed the glitches colour to blue - by this I'm trying to emphasis that I don't think this is some kind of dev tools rendered/updated visual blocks thing.

I don't know what version of Chrome specifically introduced this issue, but I've confirmed that it does not happen in 86.0.4240.198 and that it does in 87.0.4280.66 (latest at the time of writing this).

Comment: Have you changed any default Vuetify styles?

Comment: @AdamOrlov - I have a theme.js file where I've changed the primary and secondary colours and added a few custom colours, but other than that it's all stock / configured vuetify.

Comment: @AdamOrlov - I went hunting to make sure my previous statement is true. What I've found is some custom styling on the v-combobox element that seems to be causing the issues. 

Thanks then, for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The main search input is a vuetify `v-combobox` control. I've some custom styling on this control that sets a `fieldset` (part of the control's rendered HTML) to have a white background. Here's the style in it's entirety:

```
.smc-textfield-tall fieldset {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Removing this causes the visual glitch to go away. I have no idea why this would cause the glitch - there has to me some other styling (whether custom or part of vuetify) that in combination with this simple background colour causes this behavior.

I'll be digging into it some more.